# Calculate number of pages given n items

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a number of items n, what is the most efficient way to calculate the number of pages required to display n if we are going to display 20 items on the first page, and 10 items on each subsequent page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n$ items distributed over $p$ pages would look like this:

$$ 20 + (p-1)10 = n $$

So you have 20 items on the first page and 10 items on each of the remaining $(p-1)$ pages, summing up to a total of $n$ items. Therefore

$$ p=\frac{n-20}{10} + 1$$

**Edit:** As you most likely want to your result in "whole" pages and would therefore need to round up the resulting $p$ to the next integer. If you want to count "full" pages only (not counting the one that has less than 10 items), you'll need to round down. If $n<20$, then you only need one page, so you need to be careful with this formula as it might yield negative values for low $n$.

Comment: Thanks @Lisa that's perfect.

Comment: You're welcome! Please note the edit about rounding up the result, if you're interested in a discrete number of pages.

Comment: Yep, rounding up is usually what I'd need to do, but in this case I  actually need the number of full pages, so assuming I only ever use integers the formula should work as is right? Thanks again!

Comment: You don't necessarily get integer $p$'s for integer $n$'s.

Comment: Thanks that last edit was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 10, round up, and then subtract 1 if the answer is not 0 or 1.